# Interface with constant definition (review of code)

Tags: android, enumeration

In a legacy code of an Android device I've found following piece of art (definition of interface):

```
public interface ErrorIdentifiers {
    public static final int SUCCESS = 0;
    public static final int NOT_AVAILABLE = 1;
    public static final int GENERIC_FAILURE = 2;
    public static final int REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED = 3;
    public static final int REQUEST_CANCELLED = 4;
    public static final int INVALID_RESPONSE = 5;
    public static final int LIST_DOWNLOAD_NOT_FINISHED = 6;
    public static final int TIMEOUT_ERROR = 7;

    public static final int DIR_FOUND = 0;
    public static final int DIR_NOT_FOUND = 1;
    public static final int DIR_INVALID_PROVIDER = 2;
    public static final int DIR_NO_DATA_CONNECTION = 3;
    public static final int DIR_OTHER_ERROR = 4; 

    // ... and many many more
}
```

The it's then used like this:

```
resultcode = ErrorIdentifiers.SUCCESS;
```

Is it bad to use interface in that way? How to do error identifiers in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong when using an `interface` like this.

However, there's some redundancy in the code. `public static final` could be removed as redundant, as per [JLS 9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3):

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly `public`, `static`, and `final`. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.